# C++ - LoadLibrary returns 126 error for self-made DLL

Tags: c++, loadlibrary

I'm playing in custom project and trying to create a DLL in other project and link in runtime using `LoadLibrary` function, but it returns 126 error. In googled a lot, but in the most cases people debugged programs of others. But my DLL contains function `string sayHello() { return "Hello"; }`. Which project options should be applied to let me successfully load this dll? And call the function? Thanks

UDP:

```
vector<BYTE> decodedDll = base64_decode(base64dll);
string filename = string("lib.dll");
ofstream outfile(filename, ios::out | ios::binary);
outfile.write((const char*) &decodedDll[0], decodedDll.size());
outfile.close();
if (!fileExists(filename))
{
    cout << "DLL file not found " << endl;
    getchar();
    return;
}
HINSTANCE hGetProcIDDLL = LoadLibrary((LPCWSTR) filename.c_str());
int loadLibraryError = GetLastError();
if (hGetProcIDDLL == NULL)
{
    string error = "Could not load DLL\n";
    send(s, error.c_str(), error.length(), 0);
    finishSocketWork(s, address);
    cout << "Unable to load LIB, error code " << loadLibraryError << endl;
    getchar();
    return;
}
```

(it's a university work, I'm required to receive DLL from client, call specified function and return result). And .dll transfer works good -- files are equal

Comment: Are you sure you're passing the correct path to the `LoadLibrary` call? Error `126` is `ERROR_MOD_NOT_FOUND` which means the "module" could not be found. Can you please edit your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that show what you're doing? And please [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude added my code. Sorry for that, I thought I have some missing dependencies, and it's not necessary to supply my code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
LoadLibrary((LPCWSTR)filename.c_str());
```

This is a common error, trying to hide compiler error by using `(LPCWSTR)` cast. The cast is meaningless here. You mignt as well try to cast from integer to string.

Use the ANSI version `LoadLibraryA` for ANSI parameter:

```
HINSTANCE hGetProcIDDLL = LoadLibraryA(filename.c_str());
```

Or use wide string functions `std::wstring`